# Swift - Search large array based on multiple conditions

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uisearchbar, predicate

I have an array of 4K+ items, using UISearchBar and UISearchController to sort the list for matches. I would like to get sorted array by few criteria, but most importantly by the order user types first

Search controller has 3 scope buttons for

- category
- subCategory
- allCat

The items in the search array are using struct class to access the conditions:

```
struct Item {
    var title: String
    var category: String
    var subCategory: String
    var allCat: String
}
```

The standard method of filtering would be using something like this:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {

    self.filteredItems = allItems.filter({( item : Item) -> Bool in

        let categoryMatch = (item.allCat == scope) || (item.category == scope)
        return categoryMatch && item.title.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        //return categoryMatch && (item.title.lowercased().range(of:searchText.lowercased()) != nil)
    })

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Which is fine in case of few items, but if I have large array and when using the block above, plenty unrelated items with the string typed contained would be included.

I can use predicate to get better result using BEGINSWITH, but I am failing to meet the conditions for categories. I am pretty sure the code block below isn't effective and would appreciate for more economic advise. Another obstacle is that the array contains strings with multiple words. For example:

```
array = ["Apple", "Apple Freshly Picked", "Apple Green", "Pear", "Melon", "Pear Yellow",....]
```

So the result when user starts to type "Ap" should be

- Apple
- Apple Green
- Apple Freshly Picked

I kinda made it work without the conditions for search categories (struct) being met:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {

    let words = searchText.components(separatedBy: " ")

    var word1 = ""
    var word2 = ""
    var word3 = ""

    var predicate = NSPredicate()
    var array = [Item]()

    if scope == "All" {

        if words.count == 1{
            word1 = (words[0])
            predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@ OR SELF LIKE[cd] %@", word1, word1)
        }
        else if words.count == 2{
            word1 = (words[0])
            word2 = (words[1])
            predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@ AND SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", word1, word2)
        }
        else if words.count == 3{
            word1 = (words[0])
            word2 = (words[1])
            word3 = (words[2])
            predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@ AND SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@", word1, word2, word3)
        }

    } else {

        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title BEGINSWITH[cd] %@ AND category == %@", searchText, scope)

        if words.count == 1{
            word1 = (words[0])
            predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@ OR SELF LIKE[cd] %@ AND category == %@", word1, word1, scope)
        }
        else if words.count == 2{
            word1 = (words[0])
            word2 = (words[1])
            predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@ AND SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND category == %@", word1, word2, scope)
        }
        else if words.count == 3{
            word1 = (words[0])
            word2 = (words[1])
            word3 = (words[2])
            predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF BEGINSWITH[cd] %@ AND SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND SELF CONTAINS[cd] %@ AND category == %@", word1, word2, word3, scope)
        }

    }

    array = (allItems as NSArray).filtered(using: predicate) as! [Item]
    self.filteredItems = array

    let lengthSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "length", ascending: true)
    let sortedArr = (self.filteredItems as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [lengthSort])
    self.filteredItems = sortedArr as! [Item]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

How do I approach this logic satisfying the categories as well as the typing string match and length/range of the string (first word) please?

Thank you

Comment: Can I write my answer withour predicate ?

Comment: Why not .sort()?

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski - please, by all means. If it will perform what described above, even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way. I combined .filter and .sort to get the result:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {

    let options = NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive

    if scope == "All"{

        print("filtering All")
        self.filteredItems = allItems
            .filter{$0.title.range(of: searchText, options: options) != nil && $0.allCat == scope}
            .sorted{ ($0.title.hasPrefix(searchText) ? 0 : 1) < ($1.title.hasPrefix(searchText) ? 0 : 1) }
    }
    else{

        print("filtering \(scope)")
        self.filteredItems = allItems
            .filter{$0.title.range(of: searchText, options: options) != nil && $0.category == scope}
            .sorted{ ($0.title.hasPrefix(searchText) ? 0 : 1) < ($1.title.hasPrefix(searchText) ? 0 : 1) }

    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Hope this helps somebody

Comment: When i try your code with `array = ["Apple", "Apple Freshly Picked", "Apple Green", "Pear", "Melon", "Pear Yellow"]`, `searchText = "Apple"` and `scope = "All"` then i got empty array. Did you test this code?

Comment: Thank you for another solution. You won't be able to test it this way as the "array" was only visual example. Sorry to confuse you. The tested array should be "struct array" allItems = [ Item(title: "Apple", category: "myCategory", subCategory: "mySubCategory", allCat: "All"),  Item(title: "Apple Freshly Picked", category: "myOtherCategory", subCategory: "mySubCategory", allCat: "All"), etc...] ...and "scope" can have 3 options to pass:  myCategory || myOtherCategory || All

Comment: I converted this Strings to Items like: `String("Apple") -> Item(title: "Apple", category: "All", subCategory: "", allCat: "")` and doesn't work (empty array)

Comment: Try Item(title: "Apple", category:"", subCategory: "", allCat: "All")

Comment: Now it's working, but in your question you use `category` not `allCat` That's why my confusion

Comment: Yes, sorry. 'allCat' is like master category and there are more further categories to it...